# Makefile error cd can't cd

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm new in makefiles and  I'm trying  to change directories inside makefile, my problem is that I'm not able to change those directories  and I'm  receiving  this message : /bin/sh:1: cd can't cd to /home/.......

my code is :

```
 # !/bin/sh


CHECK_LIB = true`
DIR= /home/me/dir/

bootstrap:
ifeq($(CHECK_LIB), true)
cd $(DIR); ./bootstarp -c ;
endif
```

also I have tried `$(shell cd $(DIR) ; ls )`
without any luck. 
Has some a good opinion  how should I do/try ? os: ubuntu 12.04
Tks!

Comment: You have some syntax errors in your file. Is this a proper copy/paste from your original? Or did you make errors when you copied it? As listed, it won't match `CHECK_LIB` since it's value is `true\`` rather than `true`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you don't need /bin/sh on top, since Makefile is not a shell script, then, rules are written prepended by TAB. However, conditionals are not part of rules, so, they don't need to be prepended with TAB. So try this:

```
CHECK_LIB = true
DIR = /home/me/dir/

bootstrap:
ifeq($(CHECK_LIB), true)
<TAB>cd $(DIR) && ./bootstarp -c
endif
```

You can also use make shell command but not in rule:

```
ifeq($(CHECK_LIB), true)
BOOTSTRAP_OUT := $(shell cd $(DIR) && ./bootstarp -c)
endif
```

but I guess it's not what you want since it'll be executed before any rule and not considering any dependency. And this way you can grab the list in of files/folders in your makefile:

```
FILELIST := $(shell cd $(DIR) && ls)
$(warning FILELIST is $(FILELIST))
```

Comment: @catalin I am glad that I could help, now you can upvote and accept the answer (http://stackoverflow.com/about)